# Did corporal punishment also apply to women?

Tags: deuteronomy, gender

In Deuteronomy 25:2-3, it states that a guilty person (usually referred to as he) will be whipped.

> *Deut 25:2-3 (NIV)*: If the guilty person deserves to be beaten, the judge shall make them lie down and have them flogged in his presence with the
>   number of lashes the crime deserves, but the judge must not impose
>   more than forty lashes. If the guilty party is flogged more than that,
>   your fellow Israelite will be degraded in your eyes.

I assume that this law also applied to women, but I want verification on that.

Comment: Sorry I can't do more research on that, so only as a comment: do take into account Deut 25:1, where the Hebrew is using אֲנָשִׁ֔ים, which is rather "men", like in ESV, NASB, ASV, KJB, JPSTnkh and alike. Indeed, in NIV and alike you will find "people", "persons", "individuals". However, women are equal to men in terms of punishments: Numbers 5:6-7. Perhaps [this article](https://jwa.org/encyclopedia/article/legal-religious-status-of-jewish-female) could be of some help to start up your research.

Comment: The judge might be more lenient toward women as to the number of lashes.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Constantin Jinga's observations on this. It may also hep to consider the judicial mandate of verses 11-12 concerning the offending woman in that scenario.

> *“If two men are fighting, and the wife of one steps in to rescue her husband from the one striking him, and she reaches out her hand and
>   grabs his genitals, **you are to cut off her hand**. You must show her
>   no pity.”*

Also, in cases of adultery, both the man and the woman were to be stoned. It would seem women were as subject to the harshness of the law as were the men.